# Using mutate and summarize to find elements in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace vba code with R code. Currently in vba I use sumif in a range to find the total value of an ID depending on some dates. In R I'm using mutate an summarize but there's always an error. I don´t know how to fix it.

If i want to find the value for ID=1 that made some value withing 2 days:

```
#sys.Date() = 2016-01-06

df

DATES       ID  VALUE
2016/01/01  1   10
2016/01/02  2   15
2016/01/05  1   13

the result must be:

ID Value
 1  13
```

Currently, the code is:

```
df%>%
group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Total_op = if (Sys.Date()-as.Date(Dates,format="%YYYY-%mm- 
  %dd")>=1) Value else 0)))%>%
  summarize(SumTotal = sum(Total_op))%>%  
  collect
```

But the error showed is:

> Error: Column 'sumTotal' must be length X (the group size) or one, not Y

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `if else` does not work here, instead use `ifelse` or `dplyr::if_else`, here `ifesle` way `ifelse(as.Date('2016-01-06')-as.Date(DATES,format="%Y/%m/%d")<=2, VALUE,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `lubridate` we can convert the `DATES` string to a `datetime` object and filter accordingly:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

Dat <- ymd("2016-01-06") #Set a date. Can be done by Sys.Date()

df %>%
  mutate_at("DATES",ymd) %>% #convert to datetime
  filter(DATES %within% interval(Dat-2,Dat)) %>%  #filter entries in the last 2 days
  group_by(ID) %>% #group by ID
  summarise(SumTotal = sum(VALUE)) #summarise value as Sum
```